# Xcode debug variable and LLDB po dump are inconsistent

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, lldb

I ran into a situation that Xcode shows different result of one object from the result of po command in LLDB. firstly, all values in the object is nil and the object is displayed with *const type modifier, which it shouldn't be. and when I use po to get datasource variable it shows correct data. However, it shows datasource is nil in Xcode variable list.( please see following screenshot) Can anyone explain why?

[image: lldb issue]

Comment: ```dataSoruce``` and ```self.dataSource``` need not be the same in any case. Just a guess: does your code have a dedicated getter method for ```dataSource```? Maybe it checks the backing iVar for ```nil``` and sets it with a valid value.

Comment: there is no dedicated getter for datasource. and it's not just datasource. all class variables are shown as nil.

Comment: What's Xcode version you run? IIRC a bug like this has recently been fixed

Answer (score 2):

This seems like the sort of thing you should file a bug with Apple about.  Probably take more back and forth to figure out what is going on than can be easily done in this context.